# Django forms, attrs cols and rows for textarea doesn't work, why?

Tags: django, forms, widget, textarea

I'm working on a project with Django and a textarea. The textarea by default renders cols="40" and rows="10", which is not great for my page. I'm trying to use Django's widgets to change those attributes to 20 and 5 respectively. This is my code:

```
class NewContent(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"cols":20, "rows":5}))
```

Unfortunately, **the code does not change the looks of the form at all when the page gets rendered**. Meaning, it displays cols 40 and rows 10. But wait, things get really bizarre... when checking on the developer tools, on Google, I can see that the HTML code has changed to what I want! crazy!!

I also tried the following code that I found in a different chat:

```
attrs={"style": "height:60px; width:500px"}
```

Which "changes" the size of the box but... for different reasons I'm not in love with this solution.

Does anybody have an idea of what is happening here?

I have a windows 10 and use VEC.
Cheers!

Comment: you probably have some CSS rules that resize your textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have css style which defines width and height of your textarea
e.g.:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        textarea {width: 100px; height:30px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br/>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="7"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue with the Textarea. If I don't give any attrs value while creating the textarea.
pgContent = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

It takes the default value of row=10 cols=40, defined in the django documentation for textarea. I cleared out the textarea row, col defined in css and I tried this
pgContent = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 40, 'cols': 70})
No change in pg rendering. But the page source shows the new value of row, col.

I tried this and it worked.
attrs={"style": "height:60px; width:500px"}
css value supersedes the html value for row, col. I'm surprised why is it not taking the value defined in styles.css, which I have defined for textarea.

Comment: Your answer is repeating a possible solution already presented by the author of the post and is not explaining why the problem is happening, which is the author's question.